# Is there any difference between the tags (scope) and (on-topic) on meta? Should they be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, meta

I have noticed that there are two meta-tags called [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) and [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) on this meta. They look very similar to me.

[Tag-excerpt for scope](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/scope/info) and [tag-excerpt for on-topic](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/on-topic/info) are the same at this moment:

> When examining what is on- or off-topic, and why.

The tag on-topic also has [tag-wiki](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/on-topic/info).

> When examining what is [on-topic](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and why.

My opinion is that these tags two tags should by synonimized. (But I cannot suggest the synonyms - I do not have sufficient number of upvotes in those tags.)

Comment: I guess it is worth mentioning that the tag-wikis/tag-excerpts have been edited after I've posted this question. (So the tag-excerpts are not identical at the moment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not defined as such, here's my take on each tag:

[scope](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) - examining Sports SE's scope (wording, can we improve?, etc.)

[on-topic](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic) - examining whether questions are on-topic based on Sports SE's scope as defined