# Data-Driven Fantasy Projection Questions

Tags: discussion, scope

I understand questions on fantasy sports are off-topic [here](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34).

However, I have a few questions that do not fit the fantasy sports stereotype like:

> "Who do I start this week?"
>
> "Should I draft Pujols over Cabrera this
>   year?"
>
> "Should I make this trade?"
>
> The bulk of these questions will be too localized or have minimal
>   longevity

My questions are related to statistical methods of data-driven fantasy projections:

- How are season projections made for rookies?
- What factors are used to determine season projections? Weekly projections?
- Are offensive skill positions compared to their defensive counterparts (eg, WR to DB in football or PG to PG in basketball) when determining projections or are offensive skill positions compared to the performance of the overall defense?

As a rephrasing of one of the stereotype questions above:

- How can I make a data-driven decision to determine a beneficial trade?

I anticipate some of these questions would be too broad, but I am very interested in gathering data-driven information in order to draft better and set my lineups better. I [googled](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS821US821&ei=cqobXN_NJITDjgST6LPwDQ&q=How+are+season+projections+made+for+rookie+players+in+fantasy+sports) "How are season projections made for rookie players in fantasy sports?" and the results are almost all with respect to who to draft, how to draft, and lists of rookies to watch out for - not quite the data-driven approach I was looking for.

Would these type of data-driven fantasy projection questions fit within this site's scope? A lot of this information is, unless the correct combination of search terms are used, hard to find.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what your question is here - are you asking if the community thinks these sort of questions should be on-topic for Sports Stack Exchange or something else?

Comment: Probably the tag ([meta-tag:scope]) should be added here - if I understand correctly that you're asking for expanding the scope of what's considered on-topic here. (Related to the tagging: [Is there any difference between the tags (scope) and (on-topic) on meta? Should they be synonyms?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/419))

Comment: @PhilipKendall The former. These are questions I'd like to ask, but the premise I am asking them under has been established as off-topic. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 2):

My view would be that this kind of question would still be off-topic. I personally think that the use of data science to improve performance in fantasy sports leagues is an interesting subject - but that doesn't mean it is on-topic here, as the community had a pretty strong consensus that fantasy sports are off-topic.

While it's true that there isn't a general home for fantasy sports on the Stack Exchange network, that doesn't mean every question about them is off-topic. While I'm not a particularly active contributor there, I'd suggest this sort of question may be on-topic at [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

We have tags for [statistics](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) and [strategy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) and [betting](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betting) which this could have relevance to, but this is in the context of running an actual team or group of players.

Unless these methods are also of significant interest to, and use by, real sports professionals, they are off-topic for the same reason that fantasy sports in general are.

As for your three example questions, the first is too broad, the second is a list question, and the third I would expect a significant amount of narrowing (to one sport or a specific measure) or being broken into several distinct questions as it is also quite broad.